# fencing methods with passworded ssh

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper

iam using hadoop apache 2.7.1

after setting high availability in hadoop cluster

the automatic zookeeper  fail over controller zkfc will apply fencing method

to fence(stop) one of the two name nodes if it goes down

and `dfs.ha.fencing.methods` in `hdfs-site` property handles this method as `sshfence`

but my question is what about if we have a passworded ssh

can fencing happens or automatic fail over works only with password less ssh ?

is there any way to make `sshfencce` include password in ssh in configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**  In order for **`sshfence`** to work, it must be able to SSH to the target node without providing a passphrase. SSH through Key authentication is the only mode supported.

Comment: iam  new to linux and i was't able to understand what you mentioned alot  ,did you mean that with ssh with password iam not able to sshfence and i had to alter /etc/ssh/sshd_config to have these properties ChallengeResponseAuthentication no  #PasswordAuthentication no and restart ssh again

Comment: this is the value of fencing method in hdfs-site  <property>

        <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.private-key-files</name>

        <value>/root/.ssh/id_rsa</value>

    </property>

Comment: You need not change any ssh properties, by default they allow PubKeyAuthentication. Adding the above mentioned property should be sufficient. Let know if you are facing issues in it.

Comment: i had this property  <property> <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.private-key-files</name> <value>/root/.ssh/id_rsa</value> </property> in hdfs-site.xml but iam facing this problem in fencing method in zkfc log file

Comment: Next authentication method: publickey
2017-04-04 15:37:19,010 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.SshFenceByTcpPort.jsch: Authentications that can continue: password
2017-04-04 15:37:19,010 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.SshFenceByTcpPort.jsch: Next authentication method: password
2017-04-04 15:37:19,010 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.SshFenceByTcpPort.jsch: Disconnecting from hadoop-master port 22
2017-04-04 15:37:19,010 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ha.SshFenceByTcpPort: Unable to connect to hadoop-master as user root

Comment: and currently i have password ssh

Comment: should i issue ssh-copy-id  username@hostname for each other servers

Comment: Your Key authentication is failing. What do you mean by `i have password ssh`?

Comment: i mean i have figured ssh with password and if i want to ssh from namenode to another node i have to apply this password and that's what let my fencing method fails ,think so

Comment: Yes, key authentication has to be enabled for both the namenodes. Generate ssh key in both the namenodes and copy their public keys to the other namenode.

Answer (score 0):

SSH between nodes should work for effective use of `sshfence`.
More details about effective fencing can be found at

https://cornerhadoop.blogspot.com/2017/01/fencing-method-for-zk-based-ha-in-hadoop.html